# Filter on relationship's field

Tags: neo4j-ogm

I'm trying to fetch all entities for a given relationship's field match (I want my entity's relationships filled out in the result). Trying with Filter on session.loadAll() to filter on the relationship's field but I can't make it work.

My entities definition looks like:

```
@NodeEntity    
class ClockAction {
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;
 private String description
 private User user;
 private Office office;
}

@NodeEntity    
class User {
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;
 private String name;
 private List<ClockAction> clockActions;
}

@NodeEntity    
class Office {
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;
 private String name;
 private List<ClockAction> clockActions;
}
```

From that I'm need to retrieve all ClockAction entities where User.id is in a given set of Ids.

Here is my try :

```
Filter filter = Filter("id", ComparisonOperator.IN, userIds);
filter.setNestedPropertyName("user");
filter.setNestedPropertyType(User.class);
filter.setNestedRelationshipEntity(true);

return session.loadAll(ClockAction.class, filter);
```

This always returns an empty result. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Using a session.query like this

```
session.query(ClockAction.class, "MATCH p=(a:ClockAction)-[r]-() WHERE id(r) IN {ids} RETURN nodes(p), rels(p), a, r ORDER BY a.id", params)
```

works but only office field of ClockAction gets filled out on the result entity, user is always null...

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following advises from @meistermeier and annotate my relationships giving direction.

Below is my model entities :

```
@NodeEntity    
class ClockAction {
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;
 private String description
 @Relationship(direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
 private User user;
 @Relationship(direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
 private Office office;
}

@NodeEntity    
class User {
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;
 private String name;
 @Relationship(direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
 private List<ClockAction> clockActions;
}

@NodeEntity    
class Office {
 @Id @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;
 private String name;
 @Relationship(direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
 private List<ClockAction> clockActions;
}
```

What @meistermeier suggested for query did not work for me, but gave me inspiration and I found this working fine :

```
MATCH p((u:User)-[ur]-(c:ClockAction)-[or]-()) WHERE id(u) IN {ids} RETURN p, rels(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things first:

1. It is unfortunately currently not possible to filter for an `id` field because the filters only work with properties. Id fields are queried in cypher with the `id` function. (`id(n)` != `n.id`)
2. You are not looking for a relationship entity (remove `filter.setNestedRelationshipEntity(true);`)

Now you have the choices:

1. Query for another property of the `User` class with the filter.
2. Alter your cypher query with something like this: `"MATCH p=(a:ClockAction)-[r]-(n) WHERE id(n) IN {ids} RETURN nodes(p), rels(p), a, r ORDER BY a.id"` The changes are based on the assumption that the code snippets are correct and `User` is not a relationship.

**Additional information (edit):**
If no relationship is defined, Neo4j OGM will create them directed outgoing from the node you are saving. Your graph could look like this (ClockAction as root):

[image: Graph example]

Or like this (User as root with multiple ClockActions):

[image: Graph example 2]

You are not getting the `Office` because your current query path is `(:User)-[r]-(:ClockAction)` there is no information in the path about an `Office`.

`MATCH (n:User)-[ur:CLOCK_ACTIONS]->(c:ClockAction)-[or:OFFICE]->(o:Office) WHERE id(n) IN {ids} RETURN c, n, ur, o, or` is a pretty straight forward query you could use. It removes the path centric style but also loads all the data you need.
If the graph was stored through the `User` but this is just an example and can be applied however the data looks in your graph, you won't see any `User` information on the `ClockAction`s because as it saves without any hint Neo4j OGM will also expect the data related in a outgoing direction from the class you want to load.
Now it is necessary, keeping the `User` example, to add a `@Relationship(type="CLOCK_ACTION", direction = "INCOMING")` to the `user` field in your `ClockAction` class.
This will give Neo4j OGM the needed hint to put the `User` data it has in your `user` field.

Comment: Thanks @meistermeier - did not know filter does not apply to id. 

So since there is no "@Relationship" annotation on my entities, these are not relationships I suppose. Wondering how this "stored" then.

I did try your suggestion to alter my cypher, it returns the appropriate ClockAction with the User property filled, however the office property of the ClockAction is still null... Do you know why?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, however I could not manage to get your query work. But found enough info from your answer make it work in a different way (see my answer).